# How can I add multiple 'tax_query' arrays via a loop?

Tags: php, loop, advanced-custom-fields, array, tax-query

I'm trying to build functionality (using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin) to list information in a page template for all custom post types ('Product') that have specified taxonomies.

This is my current stable code, which queries the Products, but only based on the taxonomy terms I hard-code:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 10,
    'post_type'         => 'company_product',
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'product1'
            ),
));
```

I've used ACF to set up functionality in the backend to select multiple taxonomies (via a repeater field) that I want to apply to the query, so that the admin can modify which Products are returned based on which taxonomies they have.

I tried this:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 10,
    'post_type'         => 'company_product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        if( have_rows('category_taxonomies') ):
            while ( have_rows('category_taxonomies') ) : the_row();
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => the_sub_field('category_taxonomy')
                    ),
            endwhile;
        endif;
));
```

But received this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ')' in`...

As you can see, I'm trying to add an array to the tax_query for each taxonomy that's selected in the backend, but trying to put the if/while functions inside the array itself causes an error.

I assumed the above method wouldn't work, but PHP isn't my expertise so I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have no idea how and why your code should work... It has nothing in common with correct PHP syntax... But it's pretty good pseudo-code, so I think I can guess, what you wanted to achieve...

```
$tax_query = array();
if ( have_rows('category_taxonomies') ) {
    while ( have_rows('category_taxonomies') ) {
        the_row();
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy',  // <- you should put real taxonomy name in here
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => get_sub_field('category_taxonomy')
        );
    }
}

$posts = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type'      => 'company_product',
    'tax_query'      => $tax_query
));
```

Answer (score -1):

If conditions don't run inside of arrays, so you will need to write separate arrays for each condition:

```
$posts = get_posts(if( have_rows('category_taxonomies') ){array(
'posts_per_page'    => 10,
'post_type'         => 'company_product',
'tax_query' => array('taxonomy' => 'taxonomy',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => the_sub_field('category_taxonomy')),
   }else{array(
   'posts_per_page'    => 10,
   'post_type'         => 'company_product'
   )}
));
```